# Use Neo4j in Azure Devops or Azure Machine learning

Tags: python, azure, neo4j, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a project in python. My goal is to create an article recommendation with Neo4j.

Here is what I did:

1. Web scraping articles
2. Clean the data
3. Insert the data into Neo4j
4. Use Neo4j algorithms (graph data science library)

Everything is working, but only on my laptop.

I would like to migrate my project on Azure devops and azure machine learning in order to have a web app.

I have an Azure account and I have created Azure ML and Azure Devops for this project but I don't know how I can use Neo4j in azure devops and azure machine learning. Maybe with a VM or a container ?

Comment: Can you explain more on the purpose of this “web app”?

Comment: I would like to create a web app that display on an interface the articles recommended by the Neo4j algorithm. Or maybe a endpoint where a front end developer can display the articles recommended

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Neo4j but if this were my project I would focus on setting this up as a [experiment pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-your-first-pipeline). You can go through all of your individual steps one-by-one.

your pipe steps:

- Web collection
- cleaning
- Neo4j
- I feel like you need a "modeling" step in there, or else why are you using AML?
- Then deploy it to a web point in AML service.

[Here is my example of script steps.](https://github.com/BillmanH/learn-azureml) You just need to replace the individual PythonScriptSteps with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your advices @billmanH. For my project I use Neo4j algorithms [https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/index.html] and I don't know how to use it in Azure. That's why I thought about AML Services but maybe there is a better solution. I would like to have all in Azure and all steps automated. And at the end of the steps I would like to create a web app that display on an interface the articles recommended by the Neo4j algorithm